# Master Host List enterprise application

Tags: web-development, networking, security, dns

I work for a large bio tech enterprise and we have an in-house application that needs to be replaced. I am responsible for selecting third-party applications which will be evaluated by our decision makers, and I need help with suggestions.

We have a flat file called “Master Host List” that stores a list of all hosts that are granted access to our internal network. The MHL file is a critical aspect of our network infrastructure. The MHL file includes all computers, servers, VMs, network equipment, IP Addresses, DNS names, and all meta data associated with each entity. The MHL file is modified by our system administrators within the custom application. Any changes (such as adding a new server) are entered via the application and the flat file is modified.

The MHL file then is sent out to our network equipment which then implements access controls to allow the specified hosts to access the internal network.

We began implementing a solution in ServiceNow, but we quickly realized that the application is becoming a monstrosity with all of the extremely complex business logic behind it. As an example, when a server needs to be assigned a new DNS name and IP address, the system needs to remove the old DNS name, remove the old IP address, remove the linkages, create the new dns name, create the new IP address, and reassociate the server with all of the correct linkages. Since this is a relational database in a structured platform, this starts to get very complex when we get into modifying Cnames, round robins, aliases, etc. We need to keep track of all of the modifications across multiple tables and ensure those scripts are making the correct updates in the appropriate places.

What was once before a simple one-line command in our custom application has turned into multiple steps for the sys admin and a plethora of scripts running simultaneously to ensure accuracy and business intelligence.

Are there any existing platforms that offer these types of functionality out of the box?
Where should I begin looking? Who should I be speaking with?
What are the software options out there?
Anyone have any suggestions to our approach?

Master Host List contains the following entities:

Computing Devices
•   Client hardware
•   Servers
•   Storage
•   Peripherals (printers)
•   Network Equipment

Network Addresses
•   IP Address Ranges
o   IP Address Pool
•   DNS Names
o   CNames
o   Aliases
o   Round Robins
* more